# retrieve a web page without images

Tags: php

I am writing a web scraper for a specific site using PHP.
I use `file_get_contents` function to retrieve web pages.
some pages have images and images are also retrieved with the page.
In my case I don't want images to be there. (I want text only)

my question is, is it possible to retrieve pages without images? if so how?

additional info: I have checked the source of the page. there base tag is defined inside head tag and pointing to the same url.

Edit: I just notice images are base64 encoded.

Comment: `file_get_contents` will just get the resource at the URL requested. It won't fetch any images if that resource is an HTML document that links to them.

Comment: It only fetch code from requested URL, you can remove img tag from that

Comment: Your browser loads images automatically. But from a programming standpoint, an HTML page is just data. It would actually be harder to use `file_get_contents` to load the page AND all the images/JS/CSS, etc

Comment: $data = file_get_contents(); and then clean $data for <img tags or what ever you want to exclude ... functions that can be helpful preg_replace(), DOMDocument(), or see http://htmlparsing.com/php.html

Comment: Just don't request the images!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to "retrieve" the page with the images not included. You would need to parse/scrub the contents after retrieving it.

Inline with a previous comment, one method (of several) is this way if you simply need the image tags removed:

```
$data=file_get_contents();
preg_replace("/<img[^>]+>/i", "(image) ", $content); 
echo $content;
```

Comment: don't parse markup with regex

Comment: @gordonm if the extent of his manipulation is just too remove the image tags, where is harm in using regex for this?